# Why is this giving me this bug? "Exception has occurred: InvalidSchema"

Tags: python

So this is my code:

```
import requests

req = requests.post('<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php">https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php</a>', data = {'search':'Nanotechnology'})

req.raise_for_status()

with open('Nanotechnology.html', 'wb') as fd:

    for chunk in req.iter_content(chunk_size=50000):

        fd.write(chunk)
```

And it's giving me this error:

```
Exception has occurred: InvalidSchema
No connection adapters were found for '<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php">https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php</a>'
  File "/Users/lik20/Downloads/request/downloadingawebpage.gyp", line 3, in <module>
    req = requests.post('<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php">https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php</a>', data = {'search':'Nanotechnology'})
```

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter as the first argument in the `req` variable a URL of the site, not a part of it HTML structure.

```
import requests

req = requests.post('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php', data = {'search':'Nanotechnology'})

req.raise_for_status()

with open('Nanotechnology.html', 'wb') as fd:

    for chunk in req.iter_content(chunk_size=50000):

        fd.write(chunk)
```